# Let $p_n$ be the probability that the figure formed by connecting the four points $O,P,Q,R $ in this order is a convex square.

Tags: probability, limits, vectors

**(Problem)**

Let rhombus OABC be a rhombus on the plane with one side of length $1$. $\angle A=60^{\circ}  $. Let $n$ be a positive integer and $i, j, k $ are integers between $1$ and $n$. Three points P,Q,R are defined by
$\overrightarrow{OP}=\dfrac{i}{n}\overrightarrow{OA}$ ,
$\overrightarrow{OQ}=\dfrac{j}{n}\overrightarrow{OB}$ ,
$\overrightarrow{OR}=\dfrac{k}{n}\overrightarrow{OC}$ .Let T be the intersection of PR and OB.
Let $p_n$ be the probability that the figure formed by connecting the four points $O,P,Q,R $ in this order is a convex quadrilateral. Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n$.

**(MY idea)**

I've calculated $|\overrightarrow{OT}|$ which is $|\overrightarrow{OT}|=\dfrac{2ik}{n(i+k)}$
And when $O,P,Q,R $ in this order is a convex quadrilateral, $|\overrightarrow{OT}|<|\overrightarrow{OQ}|$ holds.
Although my teacher gave me a hint to use $\int_{0}^{n}\dfrac{ix}{i+x}dx<\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{ik}{i+k}<\int_{0}^{n+1}\dfrac{ix}{i+x}dx$ when calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n$.

But I can't find $p_n$ yet.

Sorry for my poor English.(I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: What is $\ T\ $?  You say you've "calculated $\ |\vec{OT}|\ $", but haven't previously mentioned $\ T\ $ anywhere in your statement of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I've edited it. Let T be the intersection of PR and OB

Comment: I don't understand how the quadrilateral $OPQR$ described in the question could possibly be a square.   If $\ \vec{OP}=\frac{i}{n}\vec{OA}\ $, then $\ \vec{OP}\ $  is in the same direction as $\ \vec{OA}\ $, and if $\ \vec{OR}=\frac{k}{n}\vec{OC}\ $, then $\ \vec{OR}\ $ is in the same direction as $\ \vec{OC}\ $.  Won't you therefore have $\ \angle POR=$$\angle COA=$$120^\circ\ne$$90^\circ\ $?

Comment: Well the question gives us $ \angle A=60^{\circ}$, and OABC is an rhombus, so that means $ \angle COA=120^{\circ} =\angle POR$ is true.

Comment: also note that $i, j, k $ are integers between $1$ and $n$, which means $P$ is on line segment $OA$,$ Q $is on line segment $OB$, $R$ is on line segment $OC$

Comment: Yes, I understand all that.  What I don't understand is how $\ OPQR\ $ can be square (all of whose angles must be $90^\circ\ $) if $\ \angle POR=120^\circ\ $.

Comment: oh sorry, the right word is "convex quadrilateral"

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think I now understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $\displaystyle \big|\,\vec{OT}\,\big|<\big|\,\vec{OQ}\,\big|\ \Leftrightarrow\ \frac{2ik}{i+k}<j$
- $\displaystyle
    \begin{align}
    \\\\\therefore\ p_n&=\frac{1}{n^3}\left|\left\{(i,j,k)\,\left|\,1\le i\le n,1\le k\le
     n,\frac{2ik}{i+k}<j\le n\right.\right\}\right|\\
  &=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\left\{j\,\left|\,\frac{2ik}{i+k}<j\le n\right.\right\}\right|\end{align}$
- $\displaystyle n-\frac{2ik}{i+k}-1\le\left|\left\{j\,\left|\,\frac{2ik}{i+k}<j\le n\right.\right\}\right|\le n-\frac{2ik}{i+k}$
- $\displaystyle \therefore\ 1-\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2ik}{i+k}-\frac{1}{n}\le p_n\le1-\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2ik}{i+k} $
- Therefore, if $\displaystyle\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2ik}{i+k}=\ell\ $ then $\displaystyle\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n=1-\ell\ $.
- Using a two-dimensional version your teacher's  hint,$$\int_0^n\int_0^n\frac{xy}{x+y}\,dydx\le \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ik}{i+k}\le\int_0^{n+1}\int_0^{n+1}\frac{xy}{x+y}\,dydx$$
- Using the substitutions $\ u=\frac{x}{m}, v=\frac{y}{m}\ $ in the integral $\ \displaystyle\int_0^m\int_0^m\frac{xy}{x+y}\,dydx\ $ gives $$\displaystyle\int_0^m\int_0^m\frac{xy}{x+y}\,dydx=m^3 \displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{uv}{u+v}\,dvdu$$
- Putting all this together you should be able to get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n=1-2\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{uv}{u+v}\,dvdu$$

The integral $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{uv}{u+v}\,dvdu\ $ isn't difficult to evaluate, but requires a fair amount of tedious calculation.  When I tried to do it, I somewhere lost the factor of $\ 2\ $ multiplying the logarithm [in Wolfram alpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+integral+from+0+to+1+of+x*Divide%5By%2Cx%2By%5Ddydx) of $\ \displaystyle\frac{2-2\ln2}{3}\approx0.204569\ $. I couldn't be bothered trying to locate the presumable error in my calculation.